# Strange output of sum of DataFrame. Why does df.sum() return Series([], dtype: float64)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

The code

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[1, '-','-'], 'Col2':['-','-',2]})
df.sum()
```

returns

```
Series([], dtype: float64)
```

Assuming that the strings may cause difficulty, but this also does not work:

```
df.sum(numeric_only=True)
```

returns

```
Series([], dtype: float64)
```

I don't understand what the output is trying to tell me and why I am getting it in the first place.

Only if I replace the strings with zeroes, than the result is as expected:

```
df.replace('-',0).sum()
```

returns

```
Col1    1
Col2    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I think it is bug.

Comment: I submited in the issues section in GH, you can track the [`issue #39903`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/39903) from here.

Answer (score 1):

Its a bug. Submitted and recognized as issue [#39903.](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/39903)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the function `sum` of pandas works as the built-in python one.. therefore, if there is only one number, you don't have an iterable, and therefore nothing to sum.

It is like you are calling `sum(1)`, the answer will be : `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

While `sum([1,0,0])` will give you an answer even if trivial

Comment: For me `df.sum(axis=1)` working, return all 0, maybe need upgrade pandas for avoid your error